# Change Postgres defaut port in windows 10 console for psql command

Tags: windows, postgresql

When I install Postgres I make a mistake - change default port from `5432` to `5434` and after all, I change the port back through `postgresql.conf`. All app connections work fine with new `5432` port value, but cmd interface unavailable:

```
psql
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5434?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5434?
```

I try to reinstall Postgres from scratch but without a result. How to change the port for windows cmd?

Comment: Did you set `PGPORT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the `PGPORT` environment variable, which must be set to `5434`.

Then `psql` will use the default port 5432.